# Decrement / increment logic in counter app with double digits

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a counter / calculator app which takes the count value from multiple instances of a Counter component and combines them as the final result. The Counter component has an increment and a decrement button that add or subtract the count value in each instance. The value cannot be negative.

The problem I'm having is that the value is supposed to show as a double digit, meaning that the starting value is 00 and increments as 01, 02 until it reaches 10. My solution was to use a string literal to show a 0 in front of the value as long as the value is less than 10, but this is causing problems with my handleValue logic, and now the decrement button no longer responds.
Everything worked as it should before adding the string literal.

I cannot seem to figure out why the string literal is causing these problems or how to fix them. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
const Calculator = ({ onClick }) => {
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    count1: 0,
    count2: 0,
    count3: 0,
  });

const handleValue = (key, value) => {
    if (!((values.count1 === 0) && (value === -1))) {
      if (!((values.count2 === 0) && (value === -1))) {
        if (!((values.count3 === 0) && (value === -1))) {
          setValues((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [key]: prevState[key] + value }));
        }
      }
    }
  };

return (
    <div>
      <Counter
        id="count1"
        value={values.count1 < 10 ? `0${values.count1}` : values.count1}
        handleValue={handleValue}
      />
      <Counter
        id="count2"
        value={values.count2 < 10 ? `0${values.count2}` : values.count2}
        handleValue={handleValue}
      />
      <Counter
        id="count3"
        value={values.count3 < 10 ? `0${values.count3}` : values.count3}
        handleValue={handleValue}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        SHOW RESULT
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Calculator;
```

Comment: You need to change the implementation of `Counter`

Comment: If the value is expecting a number then giving it a string could have a variety of unwanted side-effects.  The underlying goal sounds like you want to change the display of the value, but nothing shown here is displaying the value.  It sounds like you want to change something in the `Counter` component where it displays the value, not in the `Calculator` component where it passes that value to each `Counter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<Counter
  id="count1"
  value={values.count1 < 10 ? `0${values.count1}` : values.count1}
  handleValue={handleValue}
/>
```

Here the type of `value` prop in `Counter` component isn't `number`. If you want to do some caculation, you'd better keep the type as number something like below

```html
<Counter
  id="count1"
  value={values.count1}
  handleValue={handleValue}
/>
```

So here what you need is to show the number starting with "0" if it is less than 10. In this case you can just make some trick on the visual side of the component.

Actually, I am not sure where you are showing value (maybe in `Counter` component?), but that's where you should use string iteral.

Comment: The value is shown inside another component used in <Counter />. The issue would then be passing the state from Calculator and down 2 levels.

Comment: The point is that you should use string literal where you display `value`. Passing value as prop should be `number` type.